# Can't make HTTP Post request response: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response "Not Acceptable"

Tags: php, laravel, api, http, illuminate

I'm trying to make a `post` http request using `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http`.

My request :

```php
$response = Http::post(
            $this->api.'/auth',
            [
                'auth' => [
                    'username' => $this->username,
                    'password' => $this->password
                ]
            ]
        )->json('response');
```

While `api`,`username` and `password` are set in a `__construct` method.

This request is working well in postman. But when I run it on php server I get a `null`.
I digged in the response and I found the following :

```json
Illuminate\Http\Client\Response {#2741 ▼
  #response: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response {#2766 ▼
    -reasonPhrase: "Not Acceptable"
    -statusCode: 406
    -headers: array:5 [▼
      "Server" => array:1 [▶]
      "Date" => array:1 [▶]
      "Content-Type" => array:1 [▶]
      "Content-Length" => array:1 [▶]
      "Connection" => array:1 [▶]
    ]
    -headerNames: array:5 [▼
      "server" => "Server"
      "date" => "Date"
      "content-type" => "Content-Type"
      "content-length" => "Content-Length"
      "connection" => "Connection"
    ]
    -protocol: "1.1"
    -stream: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream {#2765 ▼
      -stream: stream resource @28 ▶}
      -size: null
      -seekable: true
      -readable: true
      -writable: true
      -uri: "php://temp"
      -customMetadata: []
    }
  }
```

Do you have an idea on how to solve this ?

Comment: As it's not our server, we're not likely able to help you. We have no idea what this server is expecting to receive or why it might be rejecting your request.

Comment: There was some issues occuring in the server. I tried to switch to local and this solved my issue temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

You could try exporting the snippet as PHP code and see if you did not miss something out.[image: How to get code snippet]

Comment: I have the same values as postman, just checked ! I can't understand why it works on postman but doesn't on my php server !

Comment: I am no PHP developer so I will just assume that this code is running on the client side. One of the reasons that come to my mind is CORS, could you check your console to see if there are any errors there?

Comment: Nothing gets desplayed in console. All I'm getting is a null response of my query.

Comment: It looks like you get a 406 status code which basically means that you do not specify the content type in the request. Try to find out the response (content type) returned by server and provide it in your request Accept header
Provide this (content type) in your request Accept header. Check this link as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields